# How to create a value in compdata

Tags: haskell

I've got the following compdata example code

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Web.Rusalka.Hello (
  iB, iV, Z) where

import Data.Comp
import Data.Comp.Ops
import Data.Comp.Show ()
import Data.Comp.Derive

data B e = B Bool
data V a e = V a

type Z a = Term (B :+: V a)

$(derive [makeFunctor, makeTraversable, makeFoldable,
          makeEqF, makeShowF, smartConstructors, smartAConstructors,
          makeArbitrary, makeArbitraryF]
         [''B, ''V])
```

(You'll note that in fact, everything in Z is a leaf node.)

Now, as I understand it, this has created two functions, iB and iV, that can be used to create (Z a) s. However, I can't for the life of me figure
out how to create, for instance a (Z Int). What do I need to put in? (Or what am I misunderstanding?)

Comment: `iB True :: Z Int` or `iV (1 :: Int) :: Z Int` produce valid, printable expressions within this module.

Comment: Okay, this is a dud question. I have no idea how this was causing a problem earlier. Sorry. If you convert this to an answer, I'll tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iB True :: Z Int` or `iV (1 :: Int) :: Z Int` produce valid, printable expressions within this module.